# Ansible Composer Module and require-dev

Tags: composer-php, ansible

I need this command in Ansible.

```
php composer.phar require --dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

Following works, but it is only added in "require" part of composer.json.

```
- name: require composer dev package
  composer:
    command: require
    arguments: squizlabs/php_codesniffer
    working_dir: ../web
```

How do I have to extend this Ansible task to have this package added into "require-dev" part of composer.json?

Many different ideas haven't worked. Thank you.

Comment: did arguments: "--dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer" work?

Comment: Thank you... it works... I tested with squizlabs/php_codesniffer --dev, in combination with command and so on.

Comment: good that it works, i made an answer out of the comment so you can accept it :)

Comment: I accepted it, I hope it works ;-)
Thank you. Sometimes you are in a dead end and don't see simply solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
arguments: "--dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer"
```